# How do I assign instance variables from a constructor, using existing variables in another class?

Tags: c#, class, constructor, xna, instance-variables

I am having trouble assigning image, name and rect. They exist as public variables in Lists of their types (Texture2D, string and Rectangle (XNA features but shouldn't really be relevant to the question)) in the main class Game1 with identical names. Those are what are being used in the call to the constructor, which looks like this...

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            Cards[i] = new Card(names[i], images[i], getShuffledRectangleList()[i]);
        }
```

This constructor call appears to work perfectly fine but I need to know how to get the private variables in the Card class to be assigned the values passed into the constructor. I might just be going about the whole thing wrong. Please help! Thanks.

```
enum CardState { FaceUp, FaceDown, Matched };

    class Card
    {
        static Texture2D CardBack;
        static Texture2D MatchedCard;
        private string name;
        private Texture2D image;
        public Rectangle rect;
        private CardState cs;

        static Card()
        {
            CardBack = Game1.CardBack;
            MatchedCard = Game1.MatchedCard;
        }

        //constructor
        public Card (string name, Texture2D image, Rectangle rect)
        {
            cs = CardState.FaceDown;
            name = name;
        }
```

Comment: `this.name = name; this.image = image; this.rect = rect;`

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel kind of stupid now, I was searching for hours and couldn't figure it out.